# How to connect multiple android devices with ADB over wifi

Tags: android, adb, usb-debugging

ADB is installed in the computer, and usb debugging is enabled on devices. Also I have connected one device over wifi successfully. How to connect more devices without having to mention the serial number of the device for every additional device with the `-s` flag like: `adb -s <serial> tcpip <port>`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes there is a way to do so without having to type the serial number.

Say you have 2 devices A (IP: 192.168.1.32) and B (IP: 192.168.1.33) that you want to connect to ADB over wifi:

1. Connect device A with a USB cable to the computer (but not B)
2. `adb -d tcpip 5555`
3. `adb connect 192.168.1.32`
4. Disconnect device A, and connect device B with a USB cable to the computer
5. `adb -d tcpip 5555`
6. `adb connect 192.168.1.33`

Answer (score 9):

A slight change in the Abdul Wasae answer, based on my experience .

**devices A (IP: 192.168.1.32)**

**devices B (IP: 192.168.1.33)**

Connect device A with a USB cable to the computer (but not B)

`adb -d tcpip 5555`

`adb connect 192.168.1.32`

Disconnect device A, and connect device B with a USB cable to the
computer,This time you need to change the port !!

```
adb -d tcpip 5554
```

Here you need to specify port as well

```
adb connect 192.168.1.33:5554
```

I also have documented this here in more detail
[Connecting multiple devices over wifi using adb](https://mymlspace.com/how-to-connect-to-multiple-devices-over-wifi-using-adb/)

Comment: curious, why you need to change the port tho? in my case it works well with the same port value 5555

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem long time ago so I decided to create [this simple bash script](https://gist.github.com/teocci/62d7f4ecc4204a641d52b7e27d7591b3).

Assuming that you already added the `adb` to the path:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/YOUR-USERNAME/path/to/adb
```

You just need to follow this steps:

1. Run this commands: to create your script (typically, you want $HOME/bin for storing your own scripts)

   ```
   cd ~
   mkdir bin
   cd bin
   touch adb_connect
   ```
2. Open and copy the script using any editor like gedit.

   ```
   gedit adb_connect
   ```
3. And make your file executable.

   ```
   sudo chmod +x adb_connect
   ```
4. Modify your path to add the directory where your script is located:

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
   ```
5. Finally, now connect your device using USB and run the script:

   ```
   adb_connect
   ```
6. Your device must be connect now, disconnect the USB cable and repeat steps **5** and **6** to add more devices. If a successful connection occurs, it will have this output:

   ```
   Connecting to LGV498bdcb2c5
   restarting in TCP mode port: 7105
   connected to 192.168.20.105:7105
   ```