# Android: can we connect multiple devices simultaneously using - adb tcpip 5555

Tags: android, debugging, adb

I can connect and run one device using adb wireless commands, but how to add more than one device.

on my pc - at command promt.

adb tcpip 5555

adb connect 1.1.1.1

1.1.1.1:5555 device connected

1.1.1.1 is the IP of the device

for more than one device, how to do ?

Answer (score 1):

This question is already answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43973839/6791222.
However, you can use "adb -d tcpip 5555" to attach multiple devices.